# Toggling checkbox only checks, doesn't uncheck

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to toggle some checkboxes using jQuery and I am using code that is recommended often when searching for toggling checkboxes, but it only seems to check them instead of toggling.

Here's a jsfiddle for it:

http://jsfiddle.net/wgHpG/

The HTML:

```
<button id="priority-categories" class="btn">Priority</button>

<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="1" id="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="2" id="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="3" id="3">​
```

The js:

```
$('#priority-categories').click(function(){

    var categories = [1, 3];

    $.each(categories, function(key, value) {
        $('#' + value).prop('checked', !$('#' + value).checked);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.checked` is not a property of the jquery object representing the checkbox element.

Use `.is(':checked')` instead

http://jsfiddle.net/wgHpG/1/

Answer (score 3):

jQuery objects don't have a `.checked` property, only DOM elements have it.
`$('#' + value).checked` will always be `undefined`, and hence `!$(..).checked` will always be `true`.

You can [pass a callback to `.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2):

```
$('#' + value).prop('checked', function(i, checked) {
    return !checked;
});
```

---

Note that IDs starting with numbers are not valid in HTML4.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery elements don't have a 'checked' property. You need to either use a jQuery method to check if it is checked or convert it back into a DOM element

```
!$('#' + value)[0].checked
```

or

```
!$('#' + value).prop('checked')
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
$('#' + value).prop('checked', !$('#' + value).is(":checked"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#' + value).prop('checked', !$('#' + value).attr("checked"))
```

Comment: Please expand your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This code, while a little verbose, will toggle as you expect - http://jsfiddle.net/wgHpG/2/

```
$('#priority-categories').click(function(){

    var categories = [1, 3];

    $.each(categories, function(key, value) {
        if($('#'+value).is(':checked')) {
            $('#' + value).prop('checked', false);
        } else {
            $('#' + value).prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach might be to use jQuery to select the nodes then just toggle on the native DOM checkbox:

```
var categories = [1, 3];

$('#' + categories.join(',#')).each(function() {
   this.checked = !this.checked;
});
```